# How do I fix a no longer responsive website?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive

I am new to all this and I am desperate to understand what went wrong here:

```
https://www.festivalcinemaafricano.org
```

This URL used to work fine on mobile devices until a couple of months ago (see the [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181113213826/https://www.festivalcinemaafricano.org)) and I really can't find the problem.

Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide following information. 1. Have you updated the WordPress 2. Did you install any new plugins ? if yes, have your tried deactivating the plugin ? 3. Have you added any new code ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have a width set on your .container class of 1151px, removing that seems to make it responsive again